# Divs are overlapping

Tags: html, css

So I have two divs that are overlapping and I don't know what caused it to.

Here's the URL:
http://dennis-reviews.netne.net/

As a side problem:
How can I center the navigation list at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `#container_info` to this:

```
#container_info {
    height: 185px;
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and to center add this css rule:

```
#navigation ul {

    width: 1024px;
    margin:0px auto;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following property in CSS for the footer `div` `clear: left;`

Answer (score 0):

Your class `.info` need to have  `max-height:180px;`in the css

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm the only one that said to set your max-hight. And you're welcome.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just blazing through these new answers and guessing that they are mostly the same :)
Thanks for yours anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add `clear: left;` to the `#footer` then that will fix it.

```
#footer {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1A1A1A;
  clear: left;
}
```

If you're unsure how this works there's a good article on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) that explains it all.